# Strange behavior of range when used as key in dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Dim dicMyHash As Dictionary
Dim rngMyRange As Range

' A1 is empty - although the outcome is the same in any case
Set rngMyRange = Range("A1")
Set dicMyHash = New Dictionary

dicMyHash.Add Key:=rngMyRange(1), Item:=0

Debug.Print dicMyHash.Exists(rngMyRange(1).Value)   ' returns False
Debug.Print rngMyRange(1) = rngMyRange(1).Value     ' returns True
```

This behavior is somewhat unexpected. Is there some type casting going on in the background? `rngMyRange(1).Value` property returns a `variant`, whereas `rngMyRange(1)` is `rngMyRange.item(1)`, which is a `range`. However, casting `rngMyRange(1)` to `Variant` gives the same results..

Also, adding keys is by value (so a copy of `rngMyRange(1)` is passed as a key). But still I cannot get why `.Exists` does not find the key..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here, we have three different values being passed around:

1. The original range.
2. `Range.Value`, which is a variant.
3. The copy of (1) which is internal to the dictionary.

If you compare these with equal signs, they are all the same. But according to `Dictionary.Exists` they are *all* different.

Why? When you use an equal sign with an object, the equal sign forces the object to call its default property. The default property of `Range` is `Range.Value`, which is why `r = r.Value` and also `r = r.Offset(0, 0)`.

But for a dictionary this isn't so smart. Think about it: *Every* call to `Dictionary.Exists` would cause *every* object used as a key to call its default property. This can get really expensive and it can potentially trigger a lot of side effects. So instead, `Dictionary.Exists` tests the following:

1. Are you comparing an object to a non-object? Automatic fail.
2. Are you comparing two non-ojects? Return `a = b`.
3. Are you comparing two objects? Return `a Is b`.

So `r` is not the same as `r.Value`, since one is an object and the other is a non-object. And if you make a *copy* of `r`, like with `r.Offset(0, 0)`, those are not the same either since they still point to two different objects, even if the objects have identical contents.

This, on the other hand, *will* work, since you will make `r` into *the same object* as `d.Keys(0)`:

```
Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim r As Range
Set r = [a1]
Set d = New Dictionary
d.Add r, 0
Set r = d.Keys(0)
Debug.Print d.Exists(r)
```

Comment: rdhs thanks - Since `Dictionary.Exists` works as you describe above the rest makes sense (and also setting `r= d.Keys(0)` in your answer).

Comment: Still, I'd use something more sensible as a key, like `r.Address`.

Comment: Absolutely. In my context, I store custom objects in that dictionary, and use their names (strings) as keys - which I get from a dynamic range using `range.value` (checking with `.exists` for duplicates). At some point I referred to a key without the `.value` part and ran into trouble. Thanks for the detailed explanation - very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason of your situation is that `rngMyRange` is recognised as an two- dimensional array and both array dimensions are passed to your dictionary.

If you change the line which adding element into Dictionary into this one:

```
dicMyHash.Add Key:=rngMyRange(1).value, Item:=0
```

it starting to work as you expect- both check points return `true`.

You could additionally analyse this situation in `Locals Window` while debugging of your code.

Comment: Hi KazJew, thanks -  good point on the dimensions. Yes, passing the value does work.. But replacing all `rngMyRange(1)` occurrences with `rngMyRange(1,1)` still returns `false` as before. Good idea re `Locals Window`, will give it a shot.

Comment: So again, passing `rngMyRange(1,1)` is still recognised as array, but `rngMyRange(1,1).value` is recognised as correct value resulting with `true` for both test points.

Comment: Oh OK, I see the point. I also noted that `.exists(rngMyrange(1,1))` also gives `false`. Is it because `rngMyrange(1,1)` is copied into the dictionary as a 2-D array?

Comment: I would rather say that it's not properly converted to take the value from array (1,1) dimension...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are putting this to use, but this will return `True`:

```
Sub test()
Dim dicMyHash As Dictionary
Dim rngMyRange As Range

Set rngMyRange = Range("A1")
Set dicMyHash = New Dictionary

dicMyHash.Add Key:=rngMyRange(1).Value, Item:=0 ' assign it with Value
Debug.Print dicMyHash.Exists(rngMyRange(1).Value)
End Sub
```

So then you'll have an item with a key of whatever's in A1.

I believe the reason it doesn't work without `Value` is that you are assigning a `Range` to the `Key`. It would make more sense to me if you were assigning the range to the Dictionary's Item.

Comment: Hi Doug thanks-I use `value` normally, was just wondering why `Range` does not seem to work properly as a `Key`. Also noted that `.Exists(rngMyRange(1))` returns false when `rngMyRange(1)` is the `Key`, and was wondering why this is the case.. But yes, Ill stick to using `value`.

Comment: I upvoted, on the grounds that the above answer provides a workaround.