# Excel VBA WorksheetFunction.IsError false positive

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I am trying to determine whether or not a cell contains an error value, e.g. due to an invalid function. My existing code uses the [Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb239394.aspx) method, but I recently came across a case which caused a false positive. The cell does not contain an error value, but Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsError returns true. Another method, VBA.Information.IsError, does not exhibit this behavior; it correctly returns false.

I was able to determine that the issue only occurs when the cell contains a value exceeding 255 characters in length. Here is a routine to verify the behavior:

```
Sub IsErrorBehavior()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim xlWSFuncCheck1 As Boolean, xlWSFuncCheck2 As Boolean
    Dim vbaInfCheck1 As Boolean, vbaInfCheck2 As Boolean

    str = WorksheetFunction.Rept("A", 255)

    Set r1 = Range("A1")
    r1.Value = str
    xlWSFuncCheck1 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsError(r1)
    vbaInfCheck1 = VBA.Information.IsError(r1)

    str = str & "A"

    Set r2 = Range("A2")
    r2.Value = str
    xlWSFuncCheck2 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsError(r2)
    vbaInfCheck2 = VBA.Information.IsError(r2)
End Sub
```

The above routine was written in Excel 2010 and verified in Excel 2007. The target application is currently running under Excel 2007.

**Question 1:** Is this a bug or is there a reasonable explanation for the behavior of Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsError in this case?

I will be switching to the VBA.Information.IsError method, but now I'm a bit concerned that I may encounter bugs with it as well. Which leads me to...

**Question 2:** Is there a more reliable way to check for errors in a specific cell?

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: Oops, schoolboy error. Added version information above

Comment: Answer below by @loannis is what I second. You should be checking for the `.Value` for error, not the range, when using `WSF.IsError`. Also, `VBA.Info.IsError` is much more reliable than going the `WSF.IsError` route, as the former can check the `Range` correctly for the error as well. See [this](http://picpaste.com/pics/Capture-vRy1sAD3.1394060144.GIF) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete response for Excel 2007, but might give some ideas for other peers to follow up.

**Question 1**: `Is this a bug or is there a reasonable explanation for the behavior of Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsError in this case?`

There used to be an old known bug with the [255 character limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213548) that was supposed to be fixed in newer versions. Your issue is of very similar nature so it could be the same source, although it is not possible to say for sure.

It seems that setting a `Value` of a `Range` equal to a `String` of more than 255 characters corrupts the `Range` itself, and makes the `IsError` check on the `Range` false.

**Question 2**: `Is there a more reliable way to check for errors in a specific cell?`

I would do it as in [CPearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx), namely checking `r2.Value` instead of `r2`, and using the `IsError` function (which is the `VBA` `IsError`) that has more stable performance. In general, checking a `Range` object for error might be tricky. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742778/strange-behavior-of-range-when-used-as-key-in-dictionary) a while ago I was getting funny results because of type casting that goes on in the background. I guess this might be the case here as well. In any case, being explicit helps (your example works as expected if `r2.value` is used instead).

Comment: The bit regarding default properties in the [answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743718/3385503) was very enlightening. Making the check explicit for `Value` is better than relying on the default property mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error, too, and in our case it was independent of the use or omission of ".value".

Suppose, in cell A1, you enter

```
=1-BINOM.DIST(35, 76, 0.1, TRUE)
```

The resulting probability is minuscule, so Excel will return 0.000000 as the cell value.

However, when you then use VBA to test

```
IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
```

VBA will return TRUE. Probably this is due to some internal rounding error checking where Excel realizes that the return value of the formula is to close to zero to be correctly calculated.

This is an unfortunate situation since Excel will display the return value as a cell value without any error or warning, while at the same time VBA will return TRUE on IsError(). I don't know whether this bug is present in other Excel functions as well, such as

```
=1-NORM.S.VERT(42, TRUE)
```

but would advise caution when working with IsError().﻿